# Python сравнение смысла фраз

Tags: python, сравнение, распознавание-речи

Есть распознавание речи

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
with mic as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)
print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

Пользователь будет говорить текст и он будет сравниваться с командами. Например

```
import subprocess
commands = {
    "открой браузер": subprocess.Popen(BROWSER_PATH)
}
```

```
Ввод: запусти браузер
```

Ну или подобный, но отличающийся от стандартной команды

```
Вывод: запуск браузера
```

Но прописывать все варианты того что может сказать пользователь прописывать, как мне кажется, долго и неправильно. Машинное обучение у меня не тянет система. Нашёл такую вещь как pylem, но она виснет в процессе установки. Как можно реализовать идею сравнения смысла русских фраз?

Comment: в заголовке заявлено "сравнение слов", а в вопросе про сравнение слов ничего нет...

Comment: Ну, тут несколько вариантов: 1 - находите максимально похожую команду по расстоянию Левенштейна. 2 - делаете стемминг - оставляете только основы слов, и их сравниваете (готовые библиотеки существуют). 3 - если pylem не устанавливается, пробуйте pymorphy2/pymorphy3